# prevent div getting pushed down on toggle with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs that's open on-click. the function works pretty smooth except that the first div keeps pushing down the second div. I want them to stay on each others side.

I created a js fiddle, 
http://jsfiddle.net/Qskxa/1/

I think the problem is in the html file ?

Thanks

```
<div id="artistsbox">
  <div class="artist">
    <ul class="ulartists">
      <li> 
        <span class="toggle">Artist 1</span>
        <div class="toggle_hide">
          <p> Hello world</p>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="toggle">Artist 2</span>
        <div class="toggle_hide">
          <p> Hello world</p>
        </div> 
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for (is it the buttons you want side-by-side?) but if you use CSS positioning, you can remove the hidden images from the flow of the document, avoiding the pushdown:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qskxa/10/

```
.toggle_hide{
    display:none;
    position: relative;
}

.toggle_hide img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Change the values/positioning to suit your needs :)

Comment: Well It looks good on the jsfiddle but on my site the div is still getting push down. =/

Comment: Are you using an image on your site, a paragraph, or mixed tags? If it's a paragraph, change `.toggle_hide img` to `.toggle_hide p`. If it's mixed content, add a wrapper around it and use `position: absolute` on that. Without seeing your site (or the exact HTML/CSS rather than a testcase jsFiddle) it's hard to solve your issue.

Comment: its a mix of image and paragraphs . will try the wrap them and see whats up :)
otherwise the page is here.

http://felipe.ungoogleable.se/gallery/progresso-2/

Comment: The problem was in a total different area of the css :)
I changed a class name artist  and it worked fine.

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Ah, sorry, I always forget about the delay -_-